# Proof of claim on orthonormal elements in an inner product space

Tags: inner-products, orthonormal

> Let $X$ be an inner product space and $\{e_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset X$ be an orthonormal set. Show that
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle x,e_{n}\rangle\langle y, e_{n}\rangle| \leqslant \|x\|\|y\| $$
>   for all $x,y \in X$.

I am seeking a hint on how to get started. I imagine this involves some manipulation of the $RHS$ to get down to inequality on the $LHS$. Any insight is appreciated.

Using the hints below:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle x,e_{n}\rangle\langle y, e_{n}\rangle| \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|x\|\|y\|$$
I do not quite see the connection to Bessel's inequality from here.

Comment: Hint: Bessel inequality.

Comment: If for all $n$ you have $a_n\ge0$ and for all $N$ you have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \le M$ then you also have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \le M$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cauchy Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) says that
$$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle x,e_n\rangle\langle y,e_n\rangle\right)^2
\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle x,e_n\rangle^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle y,e_n\rangle^2\tag{1}
$$
If we are in a Hilbert Space, we can apply [Bessel's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel's_inequality). If not, we might want to reprove it for an inner product space.

For any $1\le k\le n$,
$$
\left\langle x-\sum_{j=1}^n\langle x,e_j\rangle e_j,e_k\right\rangle
=0\tag{2}
$$
If we set
$$
u=\sum_{j=1}^n\langle x,e_j\rangle e_j\tag{3}
$$
$(2)$ and $(3)$ show that $\langle u,x-u\rangle=0$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\|x\|^2
&=\langle x,x\rangle\\
&=\langle u+(x-u),u+(x-u)\rangle\\
&=\|u\|^2+\|x-u\|^2\\
&\ge\|u\|^2\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\langle x,e_j\rangle^2\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Letting $n\to\infty$, $(1)$ and $(4)$ show that
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\langle x,e_k\rangle\langle y,e_k\rangle\right)^2
\le\|x\|^2\|y\|^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on the left hand side, and then apply Bessel's inequality.